# Minimum load current on boost converter

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, boost

I was hoping to use the LM2731Y boost converter to step up 3.6V to 7V, but I'm unclear if this will work for my load requirements. I will likely have a fairly low current draw (<50mA) and there is a section in the datasheet that lists the minimum output voltage under load that I don't think would meet my 7V output requirement. However, there is a 3.2V to 5V configuration in the application section that seems to counter this, since it show lower load currents in the efficiency vs load current graphs.

Are there minimum load requirements for boost converters?

What does Vout(min) mean in [this datasheet?](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/LM2731YMFX-NOPB/1871080)

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand your question. Normally, for any kind of voltage regulator, you have some type of limit to the max current it can deliver, and the output voltage can drop when delivering it. Normally, there is no low limit for the current - some circuits do have a lower limit, like shunt LDOs, but it should not be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

p. 15 of the data sheet mentions 'discontinuous conduction' mode. When the converter switches to this mode, portions of switching cycles are skipped (the exact method isn't clear), but the converter will still regulate at the set point down to zero load.